# Nginx: How to properly setup rate limiting?

Tags: nginx

After hard google search i couldn't find good information how to limit rate with nginx and debian.

I'm not sure where should i add that filter nginx.conf or default.
I added this to default not sure if it's right:

```
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=1r/s;
server {
   server_name Realesta74.net;

   location / {
     limit_req zone=one burst=5;
  }
```

}

Is that fine?
And also how to test it?

Answer (score 4):

Nginx rate limiting is implemented identically regardless of Linux distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, etc).  Nginx officially provides a good tutorial and explaination:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Testing can be done with multiple-connection URL tools like [Siege](https://packages.debian.org/sid/web/siege) or [Apache Benchmark Tool](https://packages.debian.org/sid/apache2-utils), and Siege this example uses 30 simultaneous connections to test rate limiting on a web page. 503 responses would show if rate limiting is configured properly:

```
$ siege -c 30 -r 1 --no-parser https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The only one thing i dont understand is this: location /login/ but i dont have that location in my website i just want to make rate limiting to whole website.

Comment: `location / {}` affects whole website if location block is required